# Model not taking all properties value from the View(new added Property only)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

This is my Model

```
public class Patients
{
    [Key]
    public int PatientId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int HospitalId { get; set; }
    public Hospital Hospital { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string EntryDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Age { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(3)]
    [MinLength(1)]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "يرجى ادخال الطول بصورة صحيحة")]
    public string height { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Ethnicity { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Note { get; set; }

    public string Condition { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "الجنسية")]
    public string Nationality { get; set; }

    public string IDNumber { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }

    public int Patient_ID { get; set; }
    public int Injury_Type { get ; set ; }
    public int Physical_Structure { get; set; }
    public int Skin_Color { get; set; }
    public int Face { get; set; }
    public int Nose { get; set; }
    public int Mouth { get; set; }
    public int Forehead { get; set; }
    public int Eyes { get; set; }
    public int Head_Hair_Color { get; set; }
    public int Pupil_Color { get; set; }
    public int Hair_Type { get; set; }
    public int Hair_Tall { get; set; }
    public int Mustache_Beard { get; set; }
    public int Eyebrows { get; set; }
    public int Ears { get; set; }
    public int Circumcision { get; set; }
    public int Jewelery { get; set; }
    public int Teeth { get; set; }
    public int IndustrialTeeth { get; set; }
    public int Det_ID { get; set; }
}
```

in the View

i tried this way

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Injury_Type, ViewBag.lstInjuryType as SelectList, Lang.HomeTexts.SelectInjuryType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Injury_Type, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

and this way

```
@Html.DropDownList("Physical_Structure", ViewBag.lstPysicalStructure as SelectList, Lang.HomeTexts.PhysicalStructure, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Physical_Structure, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

i added new properties to the model all new properties not taking any value only Zeros for the int and null for the string the old properties stay as usual taking the correct value from the view.

thanks in advance

Comment: can you show ViewBag.lstInjuryType in controller ?

Comment: 'ViewData["lstInjuryType"] = new SelectList(service.GetParameters(" and Major = 'InjuryType' and lang ='" + lang + "'").DefaultView, "Minor", "Minor_Text");'

Comment: found the solution by combine the divs in a container div the problem was that the model can't read from multi div(I don't know why)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must tries, 
"public string Injury_Type { get ; set ; }",
"public string Physical_Structure { get; set; }"